# "gluster volume status" errors out

Tags: glusterfs

Our monitoring script runs:

```
gluster volume status all
```

and parses the output analyzing the volumes and the bricks. Of late one of the Gluster-servers here started replying to the above command with an error:

> Another transaction is in progress. Please try again after sometime.

What's causing this condition and how do I clear it out? It, probably, will go away, if I restart the gluster-service completely, but we'd rather avoid such drastic a measure... Any suggestions?

We are on CentOS-6 using gluster-3.6.2 installed via RPMs published by gluster.org. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per the `network.frame-timeout` option, after 1800 seconds (30 minutes) the "operation has to be declared as dead, if the server does not respond for a particular operation" (old, but possibly still valid: http://www.gluster.org/community/documentation/index.php/Gluster_3.2:_Setting_Volume_Options#network.frame-timeout).

The logs could also contain precious information.